# Hierarchy Climbing and Descending Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following hierarchy on my `Player` prefab for what will be a very simple multiplayer shooter.

[image: Hierarchy]

It works this way, the `Controller` object has the scripts that deal with player input, the `PlayerShip` object has all of the turning, moving, shooting scripts etc and the `Camera` is just as it sounds, a camera with a few scripts on it for moving it about.

When a new `Player` is instantiated the `Control` script needs to locate its relevant `PlayerShip`, simple enough.

This can be achieved using the following code:

```
_playerShip = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.FindChild("PlayerShip").GetComponent<PlayerShip>();
```

Which works fine, the only thing is, to me that looks very clunky, inelegant and brittle. Consequently, I'm wondering if there's a better, more efficient, less ugly way of achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
_playerShip = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.FindChild("playerShip").GetComponent<PlayerShip>();
```

is redundant. That can be reduced to

```
_playerShip = gameObject.transform.parent.FindChild("playerShip").GetComponent<PlayerShip>();
```

or even use '*/*' just like you do with folder names.

```
_playerShip = GameObject.Find("Player/playerShip").GetComponent<PlayerShip>();
```

Now, instead of instantiating the Object and searching for it later on, you can actually instantiate it and retrieve the reference at the-same time.

```
GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
_playerShip = obj.GetComponent<PlayerShip>();
```

If it is a network game that you instantiate with [`Network.Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.Instantiate.html):

```
GameObject obj = Network.Instantiate(prefab,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity,0) as GameObject;
_playerShip = obj.GetComponent<PlayerShip>();
```

Now, send the `PlayerShip` reference to the `Control` script.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't being called every frame consider this:

```
_playerShip = GameObject.Find("PlayerShip").GetComponent>PlayerShip>();
```

Read more about the above here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html

If it is being called every frame look in  to this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html

Either one should be easier to understand.

EDIT: I may have misunderstood. Would rearranging the hierarchy so that controller is a parent of playerShip? Then you should be able to just look at the child, rather than going through a parent to a sibling.